# change a link_to with a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, link-to, simple-form-for

I'm working on a project where people can be hire on a job for an event.
Actually they can only "postulate" but I wan't to add the option that they can add a price with their application.

So here is my ancient code [working] :

```
<% if @current_user != @project.user %>
    <% if project_job.users.find { |user| user == current_user } %>
     <%= link_to "Retirer ma candidature", project_project_job_postulant_path(@project, project_job, project_job.postulants.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)), method: :delete, class:"btn btn-primary btn-prostate" %>
    <% else %>
     <%= link_to "Postuler", project_project_job_postulants_path(@project, project_job), method: :post, class:"btn btn-primary btn-prostate" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

And I want to do something like this :

```
<% if @current_user != @project.user %>
  <% if project_job.users.find { |user| user == current_user } %>
    <%= link_to "Retirer ma candidature", project_project_job_postulant_path(@project, project_job, project_job.postulants.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)), method: :delete, class:"btn btn-primary btn-prostate" %>
  <% else %>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job] do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :budget, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Budget moyen par personne. En Euros - €"%>
        <%= f.button :submit, value: "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I have an error with autorisation maybe you could help me switching this link_to with a simple_form_for.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : Message error [You are not authorize to perform this action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1V6X.png)
+ Terminal

```
    Started POST "/projects/1/project_jobs" for ::1 at 2016-04-04 16:39:41 +0200
    Processing by ProjectJobsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Rs6pNdhJyuqfTQWzX2HrBzYRB+dBR3g2ZAOEoqA45pBg+zEHep79ZRTiFvz3HPZkysqUa1vqHcLDZ6neFQiPvQ==", "project_job"=>{"budget"=>"100"}, "commit"=>"Add", "project_id"=>"1"}
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
      Project Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
    Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

**ROUTES :**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'project_jobs/Postulants'
      root to: 'pages#home'
      get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
      get '/manager', to: 'pages#manager'

      devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
      # , controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
      resources :users, only: [ :edit, :update, :show, :manager ] do
        resources :skills, only: [ :edit, :create, :show, :destroy ]
      end

      resources :projects , only: [:new, :create, :show, :edit, :destroy, :update, :index] do
        resources :project_jobs , only: [:show, :create, :destroy, :index, :new ] do
          resources :postulants , only: [:show, :destroy, :index, :create]
        end
      end

      post 'projects/:project_id/postulants/:id/accepted', to: 'postulants#accepted', as: 'accepted'
      post 'projects/:project_id/postulants/:id/rejected', to: 'postulants#rejected', as: 'rejected'
      post 'projects/:id/publish', to: 'projects#publish', as: 'publish'


    end
```

**MODEL PROJECT_JOB**

```
class ProjectJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :job

  has_many :postulants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :postulants

  validates :project_id, presence: true
  validates :number, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }
  validates :job, presence: true
end
```

**MODEL POSTULANT**

```
    class Postulant < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :project_job
      belongs_to :user

      validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :project_job,
        message: "You already apply to this job" }

    end
```

**PostulantPolicy**

```
    class PostulantPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
      class Scope < Scope
        def resolve
          scope
        end
      end

      def create?
        true
      end


      def destroy?
        record.user == user
      end

      def accepted?
        true
      end

      def rejected?
        true
      end
    end
```

**POSTULANT CONTROLLER**

```
    class PostulantsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_project_job, only: [ :create ]


      def create
        @postulant = @project_job.postulants.build(postulant_params)
        authorize @postulant
        @postulant.save
        redirect_to project_path(@project_job.project)
      end

      def destroy
        @postulant = Postulant.find(params[:id])
        authorize @postulant
        @postulant.destroy
        redirect_to project_path(@postulant.project_job.project)
      end

      def new

      end

      def accepted
        @postulant = Postulant.find(params[:id])
        @postulant.status = true
        @postulant.save
        authorize @postulant
        @project_job = @postulant.project_job
        @project_job.number -= 1
        @project_job.save
        redirect_to :back
      end

      def rejected
        @postulant = Postulant.find(params[:id])
        @postulant.status = false
        @postulant.save
        authorize @postulant
        redirect_to :back
      end


      private

      def set_project_job
        @project_job = ProjectJob.find(params[:project_job_id])
      end


      def postulant_params
        params.require(:postulant).permit(:project_jobs_id, :user_id, :budget)
      end

    end
```

Comment: can you post what error you are getting when you are changing to `simple_form_for` and also your **routes.rb** ?

Comment: Do you need something else ?

Comment: `price` is a column of which table ? When you are getting error i.e during loading the form or after submitting the form? Also, can you show the complete error log.

Comment: I just add the terminal error and try to change :price with :budget wich is also a column of postulant. The error come after submitting the form

Comment: Can't I try to do a 
<% simple_form_ for ... %> 
with my old and working 
<%= link_to "Postuler", project_project_job_postulants_path(@project, project_job), method: :post %>

Comment: Your form is getting submitted correctly and you are getting `project_id` and `budget` in your params. Just make sure you are handling it correctly across your controller.

Comment: **Can't I try to do a <% simple_form_ for ... %> with my old and working <%= link_to ...**  - You cannot do that directly. I think this way you have to make an ajax call which can read values from your input price field and send it to controller action where you can handle it.

Comment: Here is my problem , there is no params for postulant which is use to be and I don't know how to write it with simple_form.
I use to have this path : project_project_job_postulant_path(@project, project_job, project_job.postulants.find_by_user_id(current_user.id))

And I currently only have "@project" and "@project_job" as params which is not my goal because I want to post on the Postulant model. Also that's why it is saying that I have insufficient permissions :  "@project" and "@project_job" can only be update, create and else if the owner is doing it.

Comment: Is `price` an attribute of `Postulant` model ?

Comment: <%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job,**@postulant**] do |f| %>
Something like this 
Or
<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job.postulant] do |f| %>

Comment: Yes, what you got with this - `<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job,@postulant] do |f| %>`

Comment: I'm going to use budget for now and yes

Comment: NoMethodError at 114. 
Which is   <%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job, @postulant] do |f| %>

Comment: And 
**NoMethodError at /projects/4
undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [] **                  
For  <%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job, @project_job.postulants] do |f| %>

Comment: Try this - `<%= simple_form_for [@project, @project_job, @project_job.postulants.build] do |f| %>`

Comment: I still have a Nomethoderror but with a different message, 
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"postulants", :project_id=>"4", :project_job_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:project_job_id]

Comment: Do you have `@project_job` available to you or not ? It seems `nil` here

Comment: Seeing your template it looks, `project_job` is available to you. So you can modify your form like this - `<%= simple_form_for [@project, project_job, project_job.postulants.build] do |f| %>`

Comment: That's a good start , thanks ! I have no errors and I can postulate but As the manager I don't see the candidate because I have a Rollback. Params are good tho.
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bB5YWXjJ+Pu0I5U+E0bicAH6Pq49rhtik8q6gB66NhWDlj0Cqb2Q7W20fhl8kJrQKPGvT/D2NIZ0JDg/V9M+EA==", "postulant"=>{"budget"=>"400"}, "commit"=>"Add", "project_id"=>"4", "project_job_id"=>"8"}

Comment: BEGIN
  Postulant Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "postulants" WHERE ("postulants"."user_id" IS NULL AND "postulants"."project_job_id" = 8) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]

Comment: From above query of yours it looks you are trying to fetch postulants based on `user_id` and `project_job_id`. But `user_id` is set to NULL due to which you are not able to fetch anything.

Comment: But current_user is not NULL and it used to work with 
 <%= link_to "Postuler", project_project_job_postulants_path(@project, project_job)

What should I do then to save current_user.id ?

Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Can you post your postulants controller code.

Comment: Done at the end of the post

Comment: Where you have  `@postulant.save` in postulants controller create action, try changing it to  `@postulant.save!` - this would give you the error why transaction is rollbacked.

Comment: Validation failed: User can't be blank
- @user is Nil
current_user.id  is working tho

Comment: Yes, `user_id` is a required attribute for Postulant model. You just need to do this in your strong param: `params.require(:postulant).permit(:project_jobs_id, :budget).merge(user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Or else just add a hidden field to your form like this `<%=  f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>` and keep your strong param as `params.require(:postulant).permit(:project_jobs_id, :user_id, :budget)`

Comment: Really thank you dkp. Can I highlight your answer if someone else is interested ?

Comment: And also you are a really nice guy , I don't how I can promote you but I will If I can. Have a great day !

Comment: You can edit my answer. You can upvote and accept my answer. That would be great :) .. have a great day too!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form to this-

```
<%= simple_form_for [@project, project_job, project_job.postulants.build] do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
 <%= f.input :budget, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Budget moyen par personne. En Euros - €"%>
 <%= f.button :submit, value: "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```